# unable to print elements in a linked list in c

Tags: c

I am just learning about linked list.
While I am trying to insert elements in linked list I am unable to print those inserted elements.

```
int main()
{
    int i,x,n; 
    struct node* head = NULL; 
    printf("Enter number of elements to insert into likedlist :"); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    printf("Enter elements: "); 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        insert(head,x);
    }
    print(head);
} 

struct node* insert(struct node* head,int x)
{
    struct node* p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->data = x;
    p->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = p;
        return head;
    }
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
    return head;
}
```

here I am adding the elements to a linked list by changing it's head node(insert_front).

```
void print(struct node* n)
{
    while(n != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}
```

So, what's wrong with this code.
Output is like this

Sample Input:

```
 Enter number of elements to insert into likedlist :5
 Enter elements: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Sample Output:

```
NULL
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Use the debugger (e.g. [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)) to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* service. And you did not provide any [MCVE].

Comment: It's not my homework @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: But it is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am just not include main function in this program

Comment: Is C programming off-topic on StackOverflow?

Comment: Even with a `main` function, it is off topic here. Use a debugger, and read more about [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Remember that in C, argument passing is by value.

Comment: "I am just learning about linked list." That means it's homework.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: The code you've shown works fine. So the code you haven't shown must be broken. That's why the site rules require a [mcve]. The question is off-topic if it doesn't include a [mcve].

Comment: @ManojKare Questions without a MCVE is off-topic for [so].

Comment: @Barmar Whether it's homework is irrelevant.

Comment: My guess is you're not assigning the result of `insert()` back to `head`.

Comment: Make sure `main()` does `head = insert(head, n);`

Comment: I can do this same program in java. But I am interested to learn how the functionality works in C. That's why I am asking "why I am unable to print linked list in C?"

Comment: @ManojKare If you post the `main()` function we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @ManojKare do you understand what the other commenters are saying?  How are you calling 'insert()'?  Show ALL relevant code!

Comment: FWIW, the `insert` function can be reduced to 4 lines. After the `malloc`, it's just `p->data = x; p->next = head; return p;` Note that assigning the `head` in the function just changes the local copy of `head`. It doesn't change the `head` in `main`.

Comment: int main()
{
 int i,x,n; 
 struct node* head = NULL;  
 printf("Enter number of elements to insert into likedlist :");  
 scanf("%d",&n); 
 printf("Enter elements: "); 
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
 {
  scanf("%d",&x);  
  insert(head,x);  
 }
 
 print(head); 
}

Comment: @ManojKare By clicking the [edit] link under the question, you can add that code into the question itself, which makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @ManojKare edit it into the question, please, not in comments, and it looks like the other commenters were correct - you are calling insert() incorrectly.  Those 'return head;' statements mean something!

Comment: Thank you!  Now read @BasileStarynkevitch answer, which explains how to call insert() correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about C programming (first some good tutorial book, then some [reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and later refer to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). We cannot teach you it in a few paragraphs.

C uses a [call-by-value evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value).

<sup>So, at least for newbies, it is conventionally recommended (but not required) to never use a formal argument as the left-side destination of some assignment, because any change to a formal argument is *local* to the function having that formal argument and does not impact the caller.</sup>

So, **Compile with all warnings and debug info**: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). **Use the debugger** (e.g. [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)) to understand the behavior of your program (your bug is probably not in the code chunk you show us).

<sup>Ability to understand the behavior of an entire program, and to debug it, is an essential skill for developers. Both the compiler's warnings and the debugger can assist you in understanding the behavior of a program. See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight.</sup>

So the `head` formal argument in `insert` is a *local copy* of the actual argument from the caller.

In

```
if(head == NULL)
{
    head = p;
    return head;
}
```

you modify only that copy, not the original. So the `head = p;` above is completely useless (and confusing), you'll better just replace the block in braces above with simply `return p;`

We don't know how you call `insert`, and we cannot help more.

Perhaps `insert` should get the *address* of some pointer.... or perhaps your `main` should use the return value of it...

In your edited question, inside your `main`, replace

```
    insert(head,x); //WRONG
```

(which does not change the local `head` declared in `main`, even if `insert` is changing its first formal, because of call by value argument passing) with

```
    head = insert(head, x);
```

Comment: That's why it returns the new value.

Comment: Yes, but we both guess that OP don't use that in `main`

Comment: So that's a problem with `main()`, not with this function.

Comment: The tiny problem is believing (implicitly) that `head = p;` changes something on the calling site

Comment: Thank you guys and sorry for your inconvenience.